# Object.freeze in constructor with subclasses

Tags: javascript

If I want my classes to be immutable, I understand I can use `Object.freeze()`. Now if I want my objects to be immutable after construction, I would put `Object.freeze(this)` into my constructor as the last line. But now, if I want to subclass that, I can't add more parameters because I can't call `this` before calling `super` and after calling `super` it's immutable:

```
class A {
  constructor(x) {
    this.x = x
    Object.freeze(this)
  }
}

class B extends A {
  constructor(x, y) {
    this.y = y // nope. No "this" before "super"
    super(x)
    this.y = y // nope. "this" is already frozen
    Object.freeze(this)
  }
}
```

I was thinking about figuring out if the constructor was called via super in order to skip freezing and leaving freezing to the subclass but that would leave it to the subclass to freeze or not. How would I best approach this? With a factory maybe?

Comment: If the class you're writing is intended to be extensible, why do you want to freeze it?

Comment: I want to deal with immutable objects **once instantiated**. I understand it would not be deeply immutable but if that was easy and cheap, I would want that, too. Once the constructor ran, it should be immutable.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First of all, it does seem odd that you want to mix classes, whose fundamental tenet is basically stateful mutability, with immutability. I think, a composable factory function with composition might be more idiomatic (there might be better ways to do it than the following):

```
function compose(funcs...) {
  return function(...args) {
    const obj = funcs.reduce((obj, func) = >{
      return func(obj, args);
    }, {});
  }
  return Object.freeze(obj);
}

function a(obj, { x }) {
  obj.x = x;
  return obj;
}

function b(obj, { y }) {
  obj.y = y;
  return obj;
}

const ab = compose(a, b);

ab({ x: 1, y: 2 });
```

Alternatively, if you want to stick with the class syntax, you could use *new.target* to check if the constructor call in *A* is a *super* call or not:

```
class A {
  constructor(x) {
    this.x = x;
    // Not a super call, thus freeze the object
    if (new.target === A) {
      Object.freeze(this);
    }
  }
}

class B extends A {
  constructor(x, y) {
    super(x)
    this.y = y
    if (new.target === B) {
      Object.freeze(this)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Although `freeze` indeed seems odd, `seal` would make sense.

Comment: "*classes, whose fundamental tenet is basically stateful mutability*" - not really. It's just having methods and data properties (state) on the same object. It doesn't mean that you cannot have immutable state.

Comment: Now, what happens if class `C` extends `B` and does not apply the Object.freeze? That's the next problem, because you want end users who extend the class to be extending an immutable-instance-producing class.

Comment: A similar answer is also on 2ality: http://2ality.com/2013/06/freezing-instances.html

Comment: If this is odd, what *is* the correct way of creating immutable data structures in javascript?

Comment: "… it does seem odd that you want to mix classes, whose fundamental tenet is basically stateful mutability, with immutability …" Immutability has nothing to do with the fundamental tenet of classes. The [fundamental tenet of classes](https://www.techelevator.com/the-3-pillars-of-object-oriented-programming-oop-brought-down-to-earth/) is the encapsulation of data with behavior, along with inheritance and polymorphism if you want to get fancy. Immutability is a completely separate topic. In modern programming we want to promote immutability, as it prevents all sorts of problems.

Answer (score 3):

You might add this functionality with a [proxy's construct trap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/handler/construct), basically instead of calling the constructor function of each class you call an intermediate function which should add the functionality you need and also create the instance

Let me explain how this could be done in ES5 first and then jump to ES6

```
function A() {
  this.name = 'a'
}
A.prototype.getName = function () {
  return this.name
}
var instance = new A()
instance.getName() // 'a'
```

the magic keyword `new` does the following

1. create an empty object whose `[[Prototype]]` points to the constructor's prototype i.e. `Object.getPrototype(emptyObject) === A.prototype` or `emptyObject.__proto__ === A.prototype`
2. calls the function `A` with the empty object set as its context i.e. inside the function `this` is the empty object
3. returns the object for us (we don't have to write `return this`)

We could mimic this behavior with the following

```
function freezeInstance(T) {
  function proxy () {
    // 1.
    var instance = Object.create(T.prototype)
    // 2.
    T.apply(instance, arguments)
    // this check is added so that constructors up
    // in the constructor chain don't freeze the object
    if (this instanceof proxy) {
      Object.freeze(instance)
    }
    // 3.
    return instance
  }

  // mimic prototype
  proxy.prototype = T.prototype

  return proxy
}
```

If we call this function with a function and assign the inner function to the argument `T` we have effectively created the same behavior as new and also we can add our custom functionality inside the proxy i.e.

```
A = freezeInstance(A)
var instance = new A()
instance.getName() // 'a'
a.name = 'b'
instance.getName() // 'a'
```

If you have a subclass the freeze behavior won't affect superclasses since we only do the special functionality for initial call

```js
function freezeInstance(T) {
  function proxy() {
    var instance = Object.create(T.prototype)
    T.apply(instance, arguments)
    if (this instanceof proxy) {
      Object.freeze(instance)
    }
    return instance
  }

  // mimic prototype
  proxy.prototype = T.prototype

  return proxy
}

function A() {
  this.name = 'a'
}
A.prototype.getName = function() {
  return this.name
}
A = freezeInstance(A)

function B() {
  A.call(this)
  this.name = 'b'
}
B.prototype = Object.create(A.prototype)
B = freezeInstance(B)

var instance = new B()
document.write(instance.getName()) // 'b'
instance.name = 'a'
document.write(instance.getName()) // 'b'
```

In ES6 you can do the same with

```
function freezeInstance(T) {
  return new Proxy(T, {
    construct: function (target, argumentLists, newTarget) {
      var instance = new target(...argumentLists)
      Object.freeze(instance)
      return instance
    }
  })
}

class A {
  constructor() {
    this.name = 'a'
  }

  getName() {
    return this.name
  }
}
A = freezeInstance(A)

class B extends A {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.name = 'b'
  }
}
B = freezeInstance(B)

var a = new A()
console.log(a.getName()) // a
a.name = 'b'
console.log(a.getName()) // a

var b = new B()
console.log(b.getName()) // b
b.name = 'a'
console.log(b.getName()) // b
```

The nice thing about proxies is that you don't have to change your implementation, you just wrap your implementation inside something else

[ES6 demo](http://esnextb.in/?gist=fbef6fa9c9cb9739675f86f6f7c92f9c)

EDIT: as @nils noted Proxies [cannot be transpiled/polyfilled due to limitations of ES5](http://babeljs.io/docs/learn-es2015/#proxies), refer to the [compatibility table](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-Proxy) for further info on the platforms that support this tech

Comment: This cannot be transpiled with babel (or any transpiler) though.

Comment: @nils ty for the feeback, that's right I'll add the corresponding links

Comment: This still doesn't enforce that some third party creating class `C` that extends `B` will follow convention and use `freezeInstance`, therefore breaking the contract: you want them to extend your class, but for it to still result in an immutable instance. How do we solve that?

Comment: @trusktr  This can be solved with es6 modules. Instead of `export class A {}` we export the proxied class: `const Ap = new Proxy(A, {...});
export { Ap as A }`

Comment: @MauricioPoppe The example causes a runtime error inside of the `B` class. Example: https://codepen.io/trusktr/pen/319bca5fd52fb6cf22011bc76c325a02. It could be that things were different before the native version.

Comment: @Exodus4D That is what the above answer already tries, but it has a runtime error inside `class B`.

Comment: @trusktr I believe so, I thought it was because I used `name` which is not writable but even if I change it to `myName` it fails with a runtime error

Comment: The solution to the `TypeError: "name" is read-only` (I do not have RuntimeError with this solution as others in comments mentioned: maybe it was a RuntimeError back then) is to make B inherit from the unfrozen version of A: so invoke `A = freezeInstance(A)` AFTER the definition of class B `class B extends A {...}`. This way you declare class A, then B and only then freeze them both with Proxy. Then you can export them as immutable.

Answer (score 0):

I've a suggested answer that may have the virtue of a certain kind of simplicity.

It goes like this: don't freeze in the constructor, just freeze in the instantiation. E.g.:

```
class A {
  constructor(…) { … }
}
…
class B extends A {
  constructor(…) { super(…); … }
}
…
let my_b = Object.freeze(new B(…));
```

This approach has the extra advantages that it strongly advertises that the object (e.g. `my_b`) is frozen (and may be immutable), and provides the flexibility not only to derive classes from `A` but also to occasionally perform naughty mutations on objects when it is expedient.

In fact, it might be sensible to provide a member function that explicitly makes an object of the class immutable. E.g.:

```
class A {
  constructor(…) { this.m1 = new X(…); … }      
  deepFreeze() { Object.freeze(this); this.m1.deepFreeze(); return this; }
}
…
class B extends A {
  constructor(…) { super(…); this.m2 = new Y(…); … }
  deepFreeze() { super.deepFreeze(); this.m2.deepFreeze(); return this; }
}
…
let my_b = (new B(…)).deepFreeze();
```

The idea here is that the class `A` knows how to also deep freeze its member objects (e.g. `m1`) as well as freezing itself, in order to properly enforce the immutability of its instances. Subclasses can override `deepFreeze` in a composable manner.

For convenience, you might add a static member function that constructs an instance for you. E.g.:

```
class A {
  constructor(…) { this.m1 = new X(…); … }      
  deepFreeze() { Object.freeze(this); this.m1.deepFreeze(); return this; }
  static deepFrozen(…) { return new this(…).deepFreeze(); }
}
…
class B extends A {
  constructor(…) { super(…); this.m2 = new Y(…); … }
  deepFreeze() { super.deepFreeze(); this.m2.deepFreeze(); return this; }
}
…
let my_b = B.deepFrozen(…);
```

Comment: Making `deepFrozen` composable is simple. Community wiki? Consider it done :-)

Comment: I might go for the reverse order of `this.m1.deepFreeze(); return Object.freeze(this);` and `this.m2.deepFreeze(); return super.deepFreeze();`. That might allow for replacements like `this.m = this.m.asFrozen()` during the freezing.

Comment: @Bergi This answer still doesn't enforce for a subclass author or end user to run the freezing process. Ideally they would inherit the feature from the base class and not need to explicitly remember to extend a specific method in their class and then to call it. What the OP desires is to allow people to define subclasses that define new properties, but have the instances be frozen finally after construction completes. Unless I missed something, the only way to solve the issue would be with a proposal like this one: https://github.com/tc39/proposal-decorators/issues/308

Comment: @trusktr You could enforce the caller to use the `deepFrozen` static methods with a few ugly tricks. This is just a problem that's not well suited for OOP I think - the superclass constructor should in general not have the ability/responsibility to freeze private(ish) properties defined by the subclass, or put the other way round, the subclass should have the freedom to define non-frozen properties. And I agree with Jordan Harband's stance on the topic that a post-construction hook is not a good idea. The class should define a contract, not try to enforce it technically.

Comment: @Bergi I believe it is a matter of opinion and preference. You wouldn't have to use the feature, but I know various people who would like to have it. Anything is a bad idea if used wrong. Writing documentation goes really far in telling people how a particular design works.

Comment: I love the corrections and improvements that have been made to this answer, and it strengthens my belief in the use of the community wiki feature.

Answer (score 0):

Another really simple option is to just split off frozen versions of each class in the hierarchy.

So if you had classes A, B extending A and C extending B just add classes FrozenA, FrozenB, FrozenC which inherit from A, B and C respectively and don't themselves have subclasses.

If you working in pure javascript and aren't doing anything really crazy with metaprogramming (e.g. interogatting objects for their class and then asking if another object is an instance of that class) it won't really matter that FrozenB isn't technically a subclass of FrozenA since the language isn't statically typed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if that's your situation, but you can do the following:

```
class A{
    constructor(){} 
}

class B extends A{
    constructor(){
        super();
        Object.freeze(this.__proto__);
    }
}
```

> this is the easiest solution, it prevents the class properties to be added, note that you can't use B.prototype.X = "blah" if you do this.