# Creating an immutable object as a class in javascript

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I would like to create an object that has various methods, but the core data can never be changed. If using a class-based approach, are using private variables the only way that this can be done? For example:

```js
class Data {
    #name;
    #elements;
    constructor(name, elements = new Set) {
        this.#name = name;
        this.#elements = elements;
    }
    get name()     { return this.#name };
    get elements() { return this.#elements };
    get size()     { return this.#elements.size };
}
export { Data }; // note: why doesn't export work in StackOverflow's javascript runner?
```

What can be improved on the above?

Comment: export doesn't work since its not a module in this case

Comment: @DanielA.White I see -- is there any way to use modules with the SO code-editor?

Comment: Where would you be exporting to and importing from? You can't reference snippets as files.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the entire object to be immutable you can call [`Object.freeze`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze) in the constructor.

```js
class Data {
    constructor(name, elements = new Set) {
        this.name = name;
        this.elements = elements;
        Object.freeze(this);
    }
    get size() { return this.elements.size };
}

var obj = new Data('A');

obj.name = 'B'; // Has no effect since the object is frozen.
console.log(obj.name); // Prints 'A'

obj.elements.add(42); // This works since the object is frozen only shallowly.
console.log(obj.size); // Prints 1
```

Of course, this does not work if you just want some properties to be immutable and others not. Also note that `Object.freeze` creates a [shallow freeze](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze#what_is_shallow_freeze). Therefore new elements can be added to `obj.elements` in the example above. If you don't want this behavior, you need to call `Object.freeze` recursively on all properties (see [`deepFreeze`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze#what_is_shallow_freeze)).

The call to `Object.freeze` may pose problems if another classes inherits from your `Data` class. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37084169/object-freeze-in-constructor-with-subclasses) for solutions in this scenario.